# Insert array into multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like this:

```
{"calendar":{"date":"1","event":"1","description":"","code":"lab"}}
```

And I want to input a new array into this array but inside calendar to achieve this output:

```
{"calendar":
    {"date":"1","event":"1","description":"","code":"lab"}
    {"date":"2","event":"2","description":"","code":"lab"}
}
```

This is all happening from a form post.

```
<?php 
$dy_date = $_GET['dy_date'];
$dy_event = $_GET['dy_event'];
$dy_description = $_GET['dy_description'];
$dy_code = $_GET['dy_code'];

$calendar = array("calendar" => array("date" => $dy_date, "event" => $dy_event, "description" => $dy_description, "code"=> $dy_code));


$calendar_check = json_decode(file_get_contents('../calendar_dynamic.js'),true);

$updated_cal = array();
foreach($calendar_check as $data){
    $updated_cal["date"] = $dy_date;
    $updated_cal["event"] = $dy_event;
    $updated_cal["description"] = $dy_description;
    $updated_cal["code"] = $dy_code;
    $updated_cal = array_merge($calendar_check['calendar'], $updated_cal);
    $filename = "../calendar_dynamic.js";
    file_put_contents($filename, json_encode($updated_cal), FILE_APPEND);
}

?>
```

I cant seem to merge the added array to the correct spot in the existing array.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$filename = "../uc3_stats/calendar_dynamic.js";

$dy_date = $_GET['dy_date'];
$dy_event = $_GET['dy_event'];
$dy_description = $_GET['dy_description'];
$dy_code = $_GET['dy_code'];

$newentry_calendar = array("calendar" => array("date" => $dy_date, "event" => $dy_event, "description" => $dy_description, "code"=> $dy_code));

$old_calendar = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename),true);

$new_calendar = $old_calendar; //keep old entries 
$new_calendar['calendar'][] = $newentry_calendar['calendar']; //add new entry
file_put_contents($filename, json_encode($new_calendar)); // save to file
```

you can shorten this up if you want, but this is as close to your code as possible ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would use array_push function instead of array_merge, because in your case array_merge changes the structure of return array as u combining inner array with new array.

```
array_push ($calendar_check['calendar'], $updated_cal)
```